# How to implement a "InterpolatedVector"?

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, iterator

I have a `std::vector<double>` and I need to interpolate its values. For example with only 1 intermediate value and given a vector filled with

```
1 / 2 / 3 / 4
```

I want to access the following values

```
1 / 1.5 / 2 / 2.5 / 3 / 3.5 / 4
```

Of course I do not have to store this intermediate values (simple linear interpolation and I do not have to read them too often), so I wrote this simple class:

```
typedef std::vector<double> DVector;
class InterpolatedVector {
public:
    InterpolatedVector(const DVector& v,int steps) : v(v),steps(steps){}
    double at(int i){
        int j = i%steps;
        int k = (int)i/steps;
        if (i==0){return v[0];}
        else if (i==v.size()*steps){return v.back();}
        else {return  ((steps-j)*v[k] + j*v[k+1])/steps;}
    }
    int size(){return steps*(v.size()-1) + 1;}
private:
    DVector v;
    int steps;
};
```

It works fine and I get (almost) what I want. However, this "container" I cannot use with the std::algorithms and I do not have iterators for it. (Of course, I cannot write the intermediate values, but at least when it is about reading, I would like to use the algorithms.) I should mention that I am still lacking a bit of understanding on iterators and the like.

**How should I implement this "InterpolatedVector", so that I can do things like**

```
std::accumulate(/* passing Interpolated iterators? */ );
```

**?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that you already have the code to handle the indexing itself, wrapping that as an iterator is pretty easy. If you'll forgive me, I'm also going to make it a bit more generic.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

template <class T>
class InterpolatedVector {
    typedef std::vector<T> DVector;
public:
    InterpolatedVector(const DVector& v,int steps) : v(v),steps(steps){}
    T at(int i){
        int j = i%steps;
        int k = (int)i/steps;
        if (i==0){return v[0];}
        else if (i==v.size()*steps){return v.back();}
        else {return  ((steps-j)*v[k] + j*v[k+1])/steps;}
    }
    int size(){return steps*(v.size()-1) + 1;}

    class iterator : public std::iterator < std::random_access_iterator_tag, T > {
        InterpolatedVector *vec;
        int index;
    public:
        iterator(InterpolatedVector &d, int index) : vec(&d), index(index) {}
        iterator &operator++() { ++index; return *this; }
        iterator operator++(int) { iterator tmp{ *vec, index }; ++index; return tmp; }
        iterator operator+(int off) { return iterator(*vec, index + off); }
        iterator operator-(int off) { return iterator(*vec, index - off); }
        value_type operator*() { return (*vec).at(index);   }
        bool operator!=(iterator const &other) { return index != other.index; }
        bool operator<(iterator const &other) { return index < other.index; }
    };

    iterator begin() { return iterator(*this, 0); }
    iterator end() { return iterator(*this, size()); }
private:

    DVector v;
    int steps;
};
```

...and a quick bit of demo code to test it out:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::vector<double> d{ 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    InterpolatedVector<double> id(d, 2);

    std::copy(id.begin(), id.end(), std::ostream_iterator<double>(std::cout, "\t"));
    std::cout << "\n";

    std::vector<int> i{ 0, 5 };
    InterpolatedVector<int> ii(i, 5);

    std::copy(ii.begin(), ii.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, "\t"));
}
```

Output:

```
1       1.5     2       2.5     3       3.5     4
0       1       2       3       4       5
```

Of course, some algorithms still won't be able to do much with this sort of "collection". Trying to feed an interpolated collection to `std::sort` wouldn't make much sense (you'd clearly need to sort the underlying container). As long as the algorithm only needs to read the data, this should be fine though.

Comment: Thanks for your quite complete solution. It really helped me a lot. I just have one comment: I had to change `tmp{*vec,index}` to `tmp(*vec,index)` because I cannot use C++11. Forgot to mention that in the question. (And actually now I wonder if there is any difference other than the brackets). And one question: In the same method (overload of ++) I get a warning for returning a reference to a local variable `tmp`. Is this a problem here? Isnt `tmp` destroyed when the method returns?

Comment: @tobi303: Oops--yes, the postfix ++ (i.e., `operator++(int)` ) should return a value not a reference. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: I did some reading and finally I understand, why loops with iterators usually read `for(Iterator it=......;++it)` and not `...it++)`. So eventually I could learn something from your mistake :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use it with algorithms, fill a vector with the intermediate values. This will be much simpler.

Comment: Yes.  I was going to suggest.  std::transform or similar.

Comment: hm.. thanks for the fast answer. If this is the easiest way, I will do it like that. However, to get a better understanding of iterators, I would like to see a solution without filling a new vector, or at least some good reasons why this would be not a good idea.